# Xamarin.Android splitting and concatenating audio files

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I'm currently working on an application which records audio and save the file. Now I'm searching for a solution to split the audio file from a position (for example: split in half and have 2 audio files) and register another audio file. In the end I need to concatenate all the audio files (2 or more files) to create one single file. 
I need to do all this in Xamarin.Android.
Did anyone did this sort of things? Is it possible to do this without any library? If not, what library should I use in order to do the cutting and concatenating of the audio files. 
I would appreciate any response.

Answer (score 0):

What I have tried is to access the memory stream of the audio file. You can access each byte so you know where you wanna cut it.

For e.g if you are trying to cut a Wav file into 2 files :

1. Specify where you want to cut it (byte[])
2. Create a new byte[] beginning with Wav Header (this will be your second

   ```
   public static void WriteWaveHeader (this Stream stream, int channelCount, int sampleRate, int bitsPerSample)
   {

   using (var writer = new BinaryWriter (stream, Encoding.UTF8))
   {
          writer.Seek (0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

           //chunk ID
           writer.Write ('R');
           writer.Write ('I');
           writer.Write ('F');
           writer.Write ('F');

           writer.Write (-1); // -1 - Unknown size

           //format
           writer.Write ('W');
           writer.Write ('A');
           writer.Write ('V');
           writer.Write ('E');

           //subchunk 1 ID
           writer.Write ('f');
           writer.Write ('m');
           writer.Write ('t');
           writer.Write (' ');

           writer.Write (16); //subchunk 1 (fmt) size
           writer.Write ((short) 1); //PCM audio format

           writer.Write ((short) channelCount);
           writer.Write (sampleRate);
           writer.Write (sampleRate * 2);
           writer.Write ((short) 2); //block align
           writer.Write ((short) bitsPerSample);

           //subchunk 2 ID
           writer.Write ('d');
           writer.Write ('a');
           writer.Write ('t');
           writer.Write ('a');

           //subchunk 2 (data) size
           writer.Write (-1); // -1 - Unknown size
       }
     }
   ```

   3. Continue this byte[] with your second cut of audio to make a Wav file.

n.b. : I am using **Plugin.AudioRecorder** to record the sound and access its **stream**. It also supports real time stream access.